# rspec allow where(id: my_id).first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm writing a test on rspec and need to allow the following line for Location model:

```
Location.where(id: params[:id]).first
```

But this is incorrect (two arguments instead of one error):

```
allow(Location).to receive(:where, :first).with(id: my_id)
```

And so is this:

```
allow(Location).to receive(:where).with(id: my_id).first
```

Which would be the right way to do it?

Comment: Will be much easier if you change your code to `Location.find_by(id: params[:id])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is you could do:

```
allow(Location).to receive(:where).with(id: my_id).and_return double(first: <your Location mock here>)
```

Comment: this made it. Thanks @BroiSatse

Answer (score 0):

`where` returns a relation (an enumerable type or collection). So if you want to mock your where, you need to return a collection of some sort:

`allow(Location).to receive(:where).with(id: my_id).and_return([double('result')])`

That said, you can always replace the pattern of where(...).first with find_by(...):

```
Location.find_by(id: params[:id])
allow(Location).to receive(:find_by).with(id: my_id).and_return(double('result'))
```

This way you don't need to return a collection so that you can call first on it. You immediately get the first result.

If you really can't modify the code and also can't modify the result - you basically just want to allow a specific contract - then you can go with message_chains as described in the [Working with legacy code section](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains):

```
allow(Location).to receive_message_chain(:where, :first)
```

Comment: String passed to a double is intended to be a class name of the doubled object. It is used to check whether methods defined with a hash passed to a double are indeed defined on that class. It does nothing if there is no class defined with that name to allow better test isolation.